# .NET Core Service Layer or DAO Scoped, or both?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When creating a .NET application where the controller calls a service, then the service calls a DAO for the database work, and I'm using Entity Framework Core 6.0 for the database services, do I also add the service layer objects in ConfigureServices, or just the data layer, and pass them in to constructors?

I'm not sure this is exactly a preference, rather I'm worried about multithreading, specifically.

The scheme is: API -> Controller -> Service -> DAO -> Database then back for the result.

Sample code:

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddDbContext<CRM_MSCRMContext>();
                services.AddScoped<HomeService>();
            }
```

See above, I've added both the service that calls the context, as well as the context.

I'm injecting the DAO using the constructor:

Sample code:

```
  public CRMDAO(CRM_MSCRMContext crmContext)
  {
     _crmContext = crmContext;
  }
```

And I **could** be injecting the service into the controller, if I add to Scoped. Otherwise I think I'm just instantiating new in the constructor anyway:

```
  public HomeController(HomeService homeService)
  {
     _homeService = homeService;
  }
```

or I could use a constructor and forget injection here:

```
 public HomeController()
  {
     _homeService = new HomeService();
  }
```

Why would one be better than the other from a multithreading or database connection standpoint? I understand that this is going to be scoped per-request, so maybe it's no different than using the constructor to New the service object on every request anyway from the controller?

Thank you,
Dan Chase

Comment: may I know why would you try to do something like `public HomeService(HomeService homeService)` ? Keeping a reference of itself to itself ? For multithreading, I'm not seeing any kind of lock or semaphore here, so it's hard to tell (also what multithreading context as you mention). And for database connection standpoint, we should use DI approach as they would take care about initiate and dispose all underlying stuff for us (which again seems pretty arkward for that kind of constructor).

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. I apologize, huge typo, I've corrected with an edit. That was supposed to be HomeController(HomeService ... not HomeService(HomeService

Answer (score 0):

OK so after reading documentation and experimenting, I found it seems to be all or nothing. I had to add everything in ConfigureServices, all DAO's and all Services, as well as all Contexts. Otherwise I kept getting "Unable to resolve while attempting to activate" errors. I also had to move everything to an Interface, or it doesn't seem to work at all.

If anyone has any tips let me know, but I figured best to answer my own question than to delete, because someone might be able to fill in more info.